# How to access and modify Xcode project files from python code?

Tags: macos, xcode4, python-3.x

I am a Xcode newbie and need to programmatically access Xcode projects and methods to modify from a Python module. For example, say i have a "hello world" program in Xcode, and i need to modify the message to "Hello Python!", how do i do that from within my Python module? Please note i am talking about a Python module which is external and not in the Xcode project.

Comment: The XCode files are just files, as well, right? So you can just open them and modify them as you do with any file. Or?

Answer (score -1):

Xcode projects are bundles like app bundles.  So 'foo.xcodeproj' will be a directory, inside of which is **project.pbxproj**.

There may be other files in the directory, but they are not used for the build and direct project definition; they are user configuration and window layout and things like that for the user of the project.